# How do you add custom fonts in TCPDF with php exec()?

Tags: fonts, exec, tcpdf, shell-exec

I'm trying to execute the command which add a font, but it does not seems to work. I have permissions and other command are executed, so I don't know what is going wrong.

```
echo shell_exec('opt/lampp/htdocs/ttfinfo/tcpdf/tools/tcpdf_addfont.php -i opt/lampp/htdocs/ttfinfo/arial.ttf');
```

Comment: What errors you get? Do you want to specify absolute paths starting with `/`?

Comment: I dont get any error! And I also tryed starting with /opt/...